# How can I process bitcoin payments from a hidden service on Tor?

Tags: tor, payment-processors

I had a very simple question for which I seem unable to find an answer. I want to set up a Tor hidden service and on it allow Bitcoin transactions. How can I make this happen? The server would be running Windows IIS and is mostly for personal use.

I had a look around at BitcoinD and Blockchain.info but somehow the information there does not resonate (or I am just too daft to grasp what they are saying)

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion: Don't use windows AT ALL. Easiest way to get hacked.

also here's the answers you are looking for https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Tor

specifically this line:
"(after starting tor) Run bitcoind with -proxy=127.0.0.1:9050"

Comment: Hello and thanks. Can you perhaps elaborate on why using windows inside a VM that runs no other software and is kept up to date and has very strong passwords/usernames would be a serious risk? A part of me would prefer to use Linux, but tbh I am not that experienced with it, and could not be sure that the way I set up the Linux box would be done correctly.

Comment: There is an updated setup guide for running Bitcoin Core and Tor on Bitcoin.SE right [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/70069/how-can-i-setup-bitcoin-to-be-anonymous-with-tor).